# Why is this code exiting with return code 16?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, system-calls, multithreading

I am trying my hands on clone() system call to create a Thread. However program is terminating itself as it return from t2_thread() function. Why is this behaviour? What am I missing?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sched.h>

int t2_thread(void *arg)
{
        printf("Thread 2 (%ld)\n",syscall(SYS_gettid));
        return;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const size_t STCK_SZ = 65536;
        char *stck;
        int flags;
        stck = malloc(STCK_SZ);
        if(stck == NULL)
        {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        flags = CLONE_SIGHAND |CLONE_FS |CLONE_VM |CLONE_FILES | CLONE_THREAD;
        if(clone(t2_thread, stck + STCK_SZ, flags, NULL)==-1)
        {
                perror("clone");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Thread 1 (%ld)\n",syscall(SYS_gettid));

        for(;;)
        {
                printf("T1\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

By the way output of this program is:

```
Thread 1 (8963)
T1
Thread 2 (8964)

$echo $?
16
```

What should I do to execute for loop infinitely?

Comment: You have `int t2_thread(void *arg)` but you don't return anything. Do you want to return the output of `syscall()`? Also, you don't use `t2_thread()`'s argument anywhere, nor do you use main()'s `argc` and `**argv` . Is there any reason why you don't want to use `gettid()` instead of a call to `syscall()` (perhaps I misunderstood something).

Comment: I can't reproduce on Debian with kernel 5.2. What's the versions of kernel, libc and compiler on your system?

Comment: @schaiba I have edited my previous program where I was using these parameters, so you can ignore arg, argc, and argv. However, despite including <sys/types.h> gettid() is undefined reference for gcc. My linux version is : Ubuntu (3.13.0-117) and gcc is (4.6.3), that why I have used syscall.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas its Ubuntu (3.13.0-117) and gcc version is (4.6.3)

Comment: The version of libc would probably be more relevant.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas GLIBC version is 2.15

Comment: You're right, there's no glibc wrapper for `gettid()`. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions of GNU libc prior to 2.26 and on some architectures including x86_64, upon return from the function passed to `clone()`, the libc would eventually call `exit_group()` (with the returned value as argument which you don't pass hence the random 16) which would cause all threads (the whole process) to terminate.

It was fixed in [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=3f823e87ccbf3723eb4eeb63b0619f1a0ceb174e) (see [corresponding bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21512)).

> ```
> commit 3f823e87ccbf3723eb4eeb63b0619f1a0ceb174e
> Author: Adhemerval Zanella <adhemerval.zanella@linaro.org>
> Date:   Thu Jun 22 08:49:34 2017 -0300
>
>    Call exit directly in clone (BZ #21512)
>
>    On aarch64, alpha, arm, hppa, mips, nios2, powerpc, sh, sparc, tile,
>    and x86_64 the clone syscall jumps to _exit after the child execution
>    and the function ends the process execution by calling exit_group.
>    This behavior have a small issue where threads created with
>    CLONE_THREAD using clone syscall directly will eventually exit the
>    whole group altogether instead of just the thread created.  Also,
>    s390, microblaze, ia64, i386, and m68k differs by calling exit
>    syscall directly.
>
>    This patch changes all architectures to call the exit syscall
>    directly, as for s390, microblaze, ia64, i386, and m68k.  This do not
>    have change glibc internal behavior in any sort, since the only
>    usage of clone implementation in posix_spawn calls _exit directly
>    in the created child (fork uses a direct call to clone).
>
>    Checked on x86_64-linux-gnu, i686-linux-gnu, aarch64-linux-gnu,
>    powerpc-linux-gnu, powerpc64le-linux-gnu, sparc64-linux-gnu,
>    and sparcv9-linux-gnu.
> ```

With older versions, you could work around it by calling the `exit` system call directly (`syscall(SYS_exit, 0)`) instead of using `return`, or if you don't want to modify your function, pass a wrapper function to `clone()` defined as:

```c
int wrapper(void *arg)
{
  syscall(SYS_exit, t2_thread(arg));
  return 0; /* never reached */
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! My reputation is less than 15 so I can't up vote your answer.

Comment: @MankPan, that is fine. You should be able to accept it (by clicking the tick mark) though, unless you want to wait for someone to maybe provide with a potentially better alternative.